# tinymce-how to disable paste formatting options pop?

Tags: formatting, popup, tinymce, paste

I am using tinyMCE for pasting text or table. Whenever I paste table, it popup a message asking "Paste Formatting Options" to choose "remove formatting" and "keep formatting".
I want to set it to "remove formatting" directly without prompting the message.
Can anyone share some experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dialog is only part of a paid premium plugin called PowerPaste - if you have questions regarding that plugin you should open a support case with Tiny and we can address your questions/issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can set powerpaste_word_import and power_past_html_import to 'clean' instead of default 'promt'

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  plugins: 'powerpaste',
  powerpaste_word_import: 'clean',
  powerpaste_html_import: 'clean',
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function () {
        var selectorRemoveFormatting = $("button[title='Remove Formatting']"); 
        if (selectorRemoveFormatting.length) {                
            selectorRemoveFormatting.click();
        }
    }, 100);
```

Hope I am not late but this is not the best solution, popup will display and go away.